# Taylor Theorem conceptual question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Need to solve following--
Let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 0&  -1\le x\le0\\ x^4& 0\lt x\le 1\end{cases}
$$

IF$$  f(x)=\sum_0^n\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(x)^n + \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{n+1!}(x)^{(n+1)}$$
is the  Taylor's formula for f about x=0 with maximum possible value of n,
then what is the value of c for$$0\lt x\le 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=0\;,\;\;f^{(n)}(0)\;\text{doesn't exist}\;\;\forall\;n\ge 4\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

So you can do a McClaurin polynomial only of order three and leave the fourth derivative for some $\;c\neq 0\;$

Comment: well i found its answer by taking n=3, the c comes out to be 1/4 , but i am not sure if its correct.